# PowerBI - Exclude the last few months with 0% or 0 count

Tags: powerbi, sum, cumulative-sum

I am using the power bi running total quick measure tool to get the cumulative % after 8 months and am trying to exclude the last few months since the numbers are not up-to-date. The last few months have a 0% so the ending months are showing the same cumulative percent.

the formula for power bi:
Participation % running total =
CALCULATE(
SUM('table1'[Participation %]),
FILTER(
ALLSELECTED('table1'[Month]),
ISONORAFTER('table1'[Month], MAX('table'[Month]), DESC)
)
)

i tried editing the allselected portion but then kept getting errors. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to Filter on the visual ? 
.
Filters on This Page --> Relative Date ---> Show Items in the Last 8 calendar months (or a different date etc)

Comment: I did but because I have another goal line that I want to keep showing I can’t use it.

Comment: try to use the date as a slicer then... create months on your calendar table and add it as slicer with multiple selection... or create a 'report calendar' with both directions to your calendar table and you can adjust the reporting dates there...